# Парсинг JSON из тела POST запроса в Объект

Tags: json, curl, spring-boot

Присутствует следующий код:

UserController.java

```
package by.gear.backend.controllers;

import by.gear.backend.models.DTOs.UserDTO;
import by.gear.backend.services.UserService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/register", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String test(@RequestBody UserDTO user){
        return user.getLogin();
    }


}
```

UserDTO.java:

```
package by.gear.backend.models.DTOs;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.List;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class UserDTO {

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    @NotNull
    private int ID;
    @JsonProperty("login")
    @NotNull
    private String login;
    @JsonProperty("passHash")
    @NotNull
    private String passHash;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;
    @JsonProperty("role")
    @NotNull
    private Role role;
    @JsonProperty("orders")
   @NotNull
    private List<OrderDTO> orders;

}
```

Выполняю POST запрос на маппинг localhost:8080/users/register:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"ID\" : \"1\", \"login\" : \"testlogin\", \"passHash\" : \"hashForPassword\", \"email\" : \"qwe\", \"role\" : \"none\", \"orders\" : []}" localhost:8080/users/register
```

В ответ получаю ошибку 400:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-10-07T08:26:15.999+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/users/register"}
```

Почему отказывается парсить?

Answer (score 0):

Решение было простейшее, мб кому поможет.

В curl у JSON было поле "role" : "none", А в enum Role были только значения USER, ADMIN. Spring просто не смог пропарсить "none"  какой-либо тип.